# avoid featured post duplication in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have a homepage with multiple WP_query loops and i want to prevent the featured post from showing up in its specific category loop at the same time. i only want it to show up in the category loop when it is no longer the featured post.

here is my featured loop:

```
<?php
$featuredPost = new WP_Query();
$featuredPost->query('showposts=1&category_name=featured');
while ($featuredPost->have_posts()) : $featuredPost->the_post(); 

stuff

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

here are my category loops:

```
<?php
$categoryPost = new WP_Query();
$categoryPost->query('showposts=3&category_name=news');
while ($categoryPost->have_posts()) : $categoryPost->the_post(); 

stuff

<?php endwhile; ?>

<br/>

<?php
$categoryPost = new WP_Query();
$categoryPost->query('showposts=3&category_name=sport');
while ($categoryPost->have_posts()) : $categoryPost->the_post(); 

stuff

<?php endwhile; ?>

<br/>

<?php
$categoryPost = new WP_Query();
$categoryPost->query('showposts=3&category_name=art');
while ($categoryPost->have_posts()) : $categoryPost->the_post(); 

stuff

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At first in your second `WP_Query` args you you can add

```
$categoryPost->query('showposts=3&category_name=art&cat=-5'); // 5 assumed the id of featured category
```

Also, you can use

```
// get the category ID first
$idObj = get_category_by_slug('featured'); 
$id = $idObj->term_id;

// use the id to exclude it from query
$categoryPost = new WP_Query('showposts=3&category_name=art&cat=-'.$id);
if($categoryPost->have_posts()):
    while($categoryPost->have_posts()) : $categoryPost->the_post();
    ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
```

So, value/id in the variable `$id` will be excluded from the query. Read more on [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

Comment: hi, thanks for the help but i cannot get the second one to work? where do i place the 'get the category ID first' code?

Comment: @user2804628, as it is, put the code before you `query` because you need to use it in your `new WP_Query()`.